# How to create hyperlink on PowerBI matrix line

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to add a formated link to a matrix line in PowerBI but I could not figure out how

I've followed the tutorial on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-hyperlinks-in-tables?tabs=powerbi-desktop and it worked for the table like below:

[image]

but I need to the "ID" text to be links in this format:

[image]

With the direct link it worked, but I would like it to be formated, is it possible?

[image]